# C++11 sort collection of custom objects by several properties

Tags: c++, c++11

There is a collection of a custom struct elements:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int id;
    std::string currencyCode;
    int month;
    int year;
    int amount;
};
```

This data will be displayed in some table that allows sorting by several columns (by clicking on table columns holding Ctrl button).

Sorting a collection of customer objects by one property is as simple as:

```
vector<MyStruct> values;

std::sort( values.begin( ), values.end( ), [ ]( const MyStruct& lhs, const MyStruct& rhs )
{
   return lhs.key < rhs.key;
});
```

or

```
struct MyStruct_x_Greater
{
    bool operator()( const MyStruct& lMyStruct, const MyStruct& rMyStruct ) const {
        return lMyStruct.x < rMyStruct.x;
    }
};

std::sort( values.begin(), values.end(), MyStruct_x_Greater() );
```

But how make sorting by several properties one by other (something like sql `ORDER BY column1 DESC, column2 ASC`)?

Comment: [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) was made for this purpose. [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multi_index/example/basic.cpp) is almost literally your case.

Comment: @nwols: constantly storing and maintaining indices for all supported sort orders (more than 20 make sense) doesn't seem a particular good approach to me....

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just change the comparator. Suppose you want to order by year, then by month, then by amount, then:

```
std::sort( values.begin(), values.end(), [ ]( const MyStruct& lhs, const MyStruct& rhs )
{
   return std::tie(lhs.year, lhs.month, lhs.amount) <
          std::tie(rhs.year, rhs.month, rhs.amount);
});
```

`std::tuple`'s `operator<` does a lexicographical comparison, so there's no need to roll your own (and risk getting it wrong). To do a descending order for an attribute, just swap `lhs` and `rhs` for that attribute.

Answer (score 14):

Your need to choose the sort order ***at runtime*** differs from most similar questions (and a few knee-jerk answers you've received).  I suggest you give each field an id number, and add an function to compare a field specified by id:

```
template <typename T>
int cmp(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    return lhs < rhs ? -1 : lhs == rhs ? 0 : 1;
}

struct MyStruct
{
    int id;   // 0
    std::string currencyCode;  // 1
    int month;  // 2
    int year;  // 3
    int amount;  // 4

    int cmp(int field_id, const MyStruct& rhs) const
    {
        switch (field_id)
        {
          case 0: return cmp(id, rhs.id);
          case 1: return cmp(currencyCode, rhs.currencyCode);
          case 2: return cmp(month, rhs.month);
          case 3: return cmp(year, rhs.year);
          case 4: return cmp(amount, rhs.amount);
          default: throw ...cases out of sync with code...;
        }
    }
};

// update this as your column heading are clicked...
std::vector<int> sort_field_ids = ...;

std::sort(begin(values), end(values),
    [&](const MyStruct& lhs, const MyStruct& rhs)
    {
        for (auto fid : sort_field_ids)
        {
            int cmp = lhs.cmp(fid, rhs);
            if (cmp) return cmp == -1;
        }
        // fall back on something stable and unique
        return lhs.id < rhs.id;
    });
```

To support descending sorts, maintain an extra flag (e.g. `std::vector<std::pair<int, bool>> sort_field_ids`) then `return (cmp == -1) ^ descending;` (where `fid,descending` are extracted from your `pair`, or refer to them as `.first` / `.second` if you prefer).

Better yet, find a graphics library with a decent grid/table widget that does the sorting internally.

Comment: Thanks, yes runtime is important here.

Answer (score 9):

Solving this by assigning IDs to the fields has several drawbacks:

- Cases may not be covered (as indicated by the `throw`)
- Sorting in reverse order requires an extra flag
- It's not obvious from the code which ID stands for which field
- It's not easily extensible (you always have to update your ID mappings)

---

Alternatively, you could define "comparators", that return `-1`, `0` or `1`, depending on whether the first argument is smaller than, equal to or greater than the second, respectively. These comparators can then be combined and reversed quite generically, and used as a sorting predicate.

Given a set of these comparators for the fields of your struct, you may compose them like this:

```
Comparator byYearReverseAndMonth = compose(reverse(byYear), byMonth);
std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), with(byYearReverseAndMonth));
```

> Edit in response to the comment:
>
> Of course it is **not** necessary to define each combination of comparators and reverse comparators at compile time. Instead, one can collect the desired comparators for the next sort at runtime, for example, in a `vector<Comparator>`. The comparator instances could, for example, be associated with the columns of a table:
>
> ```
> vector<Comparator> comparators;
> for (each selected column) {
>     comparators.push_pack(comparatorFor(column));
> }
> ```
>
> These comparators can then be composed into a single one, with a simple loop over all comparators:
>
> ```
> Comparator composedComparator = comparators[0];
> for (int i=1; i<comparators.size(); ++i) {
>     composedComparator = compose(comparator, comparators[i]);
> }
>
> sort(v.begin(),v.end(),with(composedComparator));
> ```

A sketch of what this may look like:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct MyStruct
{
    int id;
    std::string currencyCode;
    int month;
    int year;
    int amount;
};

typedef std::function<int(const MyStruct& s0, const MyStruct& s1)> Comparator;
typedef std::function<bool(const MyStruct& s0, const MyStruct& s1)> Predicate;

template <typename T>
std::function<int(const T&, const T&)> compose(
    std::function<int(const T&, const T&)> c0,
    std::function<int(const T&, const T&)> c1)
{
    return[c0, c1](const T& t0, const T& t1) -> int
    {
        int r0 = c0(t0, t1);
        if (r0 != 0)
        {
            return r0;
        }
        return c1(t0, t1);
    };
}

template <typename T>
std::function<int(const T&, const T&)> reverse(
    std::function<int(const T&, const T&)> c)
{
    return[c](const T& t0, const T& t1) -> int
    {
        return -c(t0, t1);
    };
}

template <typename T>
std::function<bool(const T&, const T&)> with(
    std::function<int(const T&, const T&)> comparator)
{
    return[comparator](const T& t0, const T& t1) 
    {
        return comparator(t0, t1) < 0;
    };
}


void print(std::vector<MyStruct>& values)
{
    for (auto it = values.begin(); it != values.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << (*it).month << "-"
            << (*it).year << " id "
            << (*it).id << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<MyStruct> values;

    MyStruct m;
    m.year = 1981; m.month = 1; m.id = 4;  values.push_back(m);
    m.year = 1980; m.month = 2; m.id = 5;  values.push_back(m);
    m.year = 1980; m.month = 4; m.id = 2;  values.push_back(m);
    m.year = 1980; m.month = 3; m.id = 3;  values.push_back(m);
    m.year = 1980; m.month = 4; m.id = 1;  values.push_back(m);

    std::cout << "Before sorting" << std::endl;
    print(values);

    Comparator byMonth = [](const MyStruct& s0, const MyStruct& s1)
    {
        if (s0.month < s1.month) return -1;
        if (s0.month > s1.month) return  1;
        return 0;
    };
    Comparator byYear = [](const MyStruct& s0, const MyStruct& s1)
    {
        if (s0.year < s1.year) return -1;
        if (s0.year > s1.year) return  1;
        return 0;
    };
    Comparator byId = [](const MyStruct& s0, const MyStruct& s1)
    {
        if (s0.id < s1.id) return -1;
        if (s0.id > s1.id) return  1;
        return 0;
    };

    Comparator byYearAndMonth = compose(byYear, byMonth);
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), with(byYearAndMonth));

    std::cout << "After sorting by year and month:" << std::endl;
    print(values);


    Comparator byYearReverseAndMonth = compose(reverse(byYear), byMonth);
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), with(byYearReverseAndMonth));

    std::cout << "After sorting by year reverse and month:" << std::endl;
    print(values);


    Comparator byYearAndMonthAndId = compose(byYearAndMonth, byId);
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), with(byYearAndMonthAndId));

    std::cout << "After sorting by year and month and id:" << std::endl;
    print(values);

    return 0;
}
```

<sub>(Apologies for potential faux pas, I'm a C++ newbie)</sub>

Comment: The only thing you need to make Comparators for all possible combinations here that will be a lot of work, and when new property is added to enum - need to change all comparators again.

Comment: @Zelid Maybe I misunderstood your requirements. But I think that there is only **one** comparator needed for **each** property. (Of course, if it was necessary to create each possible combination upfront (yielding a combinatical explosion and an exponential number of comparators), this would not be feasible). But here, the *combinations* can then be assembled at runtime. E.g. one can compose all comparators that are contained, for example, in a `vector<Comparator>` - no matter which comparators this are, and whether some of them are actually `reverse` comparators.

Answer (score 5):

Use next key only if values of current key are equal:

```
[ ]( const MyStruct& lhs, const MyStruct& rhs )
{
    if(lhs.key1 != rhs.key1) 
        return lhs.key1 < rhs.key1;

    if(lhs.key2 != rhs.key2) 
        return lhs.key2 < rhs.key2;

    ...    

    return lhs.keyN < rhs.keyN;
}
```

In this example, entries will be ordered accroding `key1`, than, `key2` and so on up to `keyN`.

Answer (score 4):

Ordering by several attributes means to define an order of importance. For example, ordering by year, month: year is more important than month:

```
vector<MyStruct> values;
std::sort( values.begin( ), values.end( ), [ ]( const MyStruct& lhs, const MyStruct& rhs )
{
   return lhs.year < rhs.year || ( lhs.year == rhs.year && lhs.month < rhs.month );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit cumbersome way to accomplish what your looking for is to do it in several steps (this would work in C++03 as well)

```
struct ColumnOneDESC{...};
struct ColumnTwoASC{...};
...
std::stable_sort( values.begin(), values.end(), ColumnTwoASC());
std::stable_sort( values.begin(), values.end(), ColumnOneDESC());
...
```

And of cource you could make it more generic by using std::not or such